# React - Unexpected token, expected - syntax error

Tags: reactjs, syntax, syntax-error, var

I am getting a syntax error in my react app in my src/app.js file. I have attached pictures that describe the problem. The error is on line 74. [part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qfxu.png)[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWyGs.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There is not enough information in your question for us to help you, sadly. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please show the code where you are getting the error in the picture. That picture alone does not help.

Comment: It is line 74 "var."

Comment: Yes, but you need to show the surrounding code, as it makes no sense on its own.

Comment: I will post another picture to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the block with }) instead of } at line 71

Comment: That fixed the problem, but now it is throwing another problem at me.

Comment: Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
  Line 26:  'create' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 26:  'react' is not defined   no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: 26var SearchExample = create-react-class{
27
28    getInitialState(){
29        return { searchString: '' };
30    };

    handleChange(e){

        // If you comment out this line, the text box will not change its value.
        // This is because in React, an input cannot change independently of the value
        // that was assigned to it. In our case this is this.state.searchString.